# ReactJs - Child not re rendering when it receives new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of persons which I pass as props to to child.
If I delete/add another person to the array the child **does** update.

However, if I change a property of one of the persons (e.g name) then it's like the child does not notice that the props are different.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I checked that the state on parent updates correctly.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    this.state = {
          persons: []
     }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getPersons(); //This function sets the state of parent
    }

   getPersons = () => fetch('/persons')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(persons => this.setState({persons: persons}))
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Could not fetch persons')
    })

    render() {
      <Child persons={this.state.persons}/>
      <Child2 getPersons={this.getPersons}/>
 }

class Child2 extends Component {

   addPerson() {
     //Functionality to add person
     ... this.props getPersons();
   }
   updatePerson() {
     //Functionality to update person
     ... this.props getPersons();
   }

   deletePerson() {
     //Functionality to delete person
     ... this.props getPersons();
   }
```

Note: The add/update/delete functionality are all done with a fetch to the API with a POST/PUT/DELETE, respectively. I can **verify** that the state of Parent updates when I do all 3 things (I can see the name changing of parent state and EVEN on child props it changes but it does not update)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Can you show us some code, please? Without it, it's gonna be hard to help you.

Comment: @estus Yeah sure, sorry - I have edited the question

Comment: @GlebKost Sorry, updated now

Comment: Please share getPersons code and as well as Child component code

Comment: @HemadriDasari Sure - added it now! It's just a plain fetch

Comment: @Alex5207 Can you please specify in which way properties of a person (e.g. name) are changed?

Comment: @antonku please create stackblitz to reproduce an issue

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain the problem. *I change a property of one of the persons (e.g name) then it's like the child does not notice that the props are different* - this isn't covered.